# Need help deleting duplicate rows in Amazon Redshift DB

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, duplicates, row

I have a table in Redshift which has some duplicate rows that I need to delete somehow. I want to keep only one row for each user_id, level and type levelup. A user can only level up one time per level. Example of the table looks like this:

```
version  date        timestamp            user_id  level  type
1.0.0    2016-05-10  2016-05-10 14:53:58  1234     13     levelup
1.0.0    2016-05-10  2016-05-10 14:53:25  1234     13     levelup
1.0.0    2016-05-10  2016-05-10 14:52:03  1234     13     levelup
1.0.0    2016-05-10  2016-05-10 14:52:03  1234     13     levelup
1.0.0    2016-05-10  2016-05-10 14:52:03  1234     13     levelup
```

I've tried looking into queries that work for other databases but haven't found anything that would work with Redshift. Using `TOP` or `min(timestamp)`, I'm also unable to use `LIMIT` even if I know how many duplicates there are. I believe using a self-join table won't work either since there is nothing unique to compare?

Is there any solution that doesn't require me to copy all unique rows into a new table?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the `row_number()` function?

In addition, can you create a unique id column and populate every row with this id.

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
              FROM (SELECT id,
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY  user_id,level,type ORDER BY timestamp) AS rnum
                     FROM tablename) t
              WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Examples_of_WF_ROW_NUMBER_WF.html

Comment: This seemed to return back all the rows? I did a `SELECT` first since I'm weary of deleting the data until I'm confident it targets the correct rows. But I'm seeing this is supposed to target all but the one assigned row 1, didn't seem to do that though.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the query. Can you try again a select statement. In order this to work you have to create an id column. Can you change the table so you have a unique id?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to add a column to this table. Not having unique ids is the problem I'm facing.

Comment: In your example data, the timestamp happens to be unique enough, but this may not be the case for all records. Can you confirm either way? A unique ID is pretty key to relational databases so give it some thought.